# Unable to Install iOS App from IPA File - Downloading but Not Installing

Tags: ios, gitlab, ipa

I'm currently working on distributing an iOS app using an IPA file hosted on GitLab. While the IPA file is downloading successfully, the app isn't installing on iOS devices. I've followed the steps outlined in my deployment process, but I'm encountering issues with the installation phase.

I've uploaded the IPA file to GitLab, created a manifest file, and included an HTML page with an installation link. However, despite successful downloads, the app isn't installing on iOS devices. I've verified the URL paths, ensured correct MIME types, and confirmed the signing with the appropriate distribution certificate.

Comment: Why exactly it cannot be installed? Is there any error or anything?

Comment: Is the app ad-hoc signed and does it include a provisioning profile that contains the udid of the device that you are trying to install on?